# Excel 2007(.xlsx) Reading code using POI 3.5 in java?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have downloaded latest **POI version 3.5**.  I want to read the **Excel file (.xlsx format)** using the POI.

If anybody has any **Example source code** or any **URL** or any other **code snippet** which can read the Excel file (.xlsx format) using the latest version of POI,which would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mishal Shah

Comment: Have a look at this answers, this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52089651/9539850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [XLSX to CSV](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) Converter example for POI, and you can find more examples [here](https://github.com/apache/poi/tree/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi).

Comment: Thanks for help.I have taken the sample codes from it but still i am getting one weird problem.if you knew or faced such kind of problem.
I have added all the POI 3.5 provided jars into the project.But, in the netbeans and eclipse in both cases it is giving error/exception.
Generated exception is below:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
 at ExcelSheetCreation.main(ExcelSheetCreation.java:38)

All the users having same kind of problem and nothing like whole solution given.

Please help me out in this case also.

Thanks,

Mishal Shah

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snipet which can help you for reading excel 2007 format file... Actually there are 2 diff class for reading excel file one is for the up to excel 2003 and one is latest one...

Code >>>

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(destDir); 
POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(inputStream); 
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(salesFileName); 
XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0); 
totalRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); 
System.out.println("total no of rows >>>>"+totalRows);
```