# reading xlsx file in Java

Tags: java, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read xlsx file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267025/read-xlsx-file-in-java)

what kind of Java API can you use to read xlsx file?  I tried jxl, it's getting 
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273277/xlsx-file-reading-in-java) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895483/excel-2007-xlsx-reading-code-using-poi-3-5-in-java) for even more answers. If you're using Java, POI is the way to go.